# How can I connect two parallel 2d polygons to create a seamless 3d mesh?

Tags: c#, algorithm, polygon

Suppose I have two polygons, one just above the other like this:

[image: Two polygons]

I'd like to connect up their vertices to create a 3d mesh out of triangles around their perimeters. This picture shows one way you might do this (orange lines represent triangle edges):

[image: Two polygons, connected with triangles]

This sort of thing can be done intuitively by a human, but I'm having real trouble translating it into a working algorithm.

The polygons are stored as a `List<Vector2>`. They will always be simple, and may be concave.

Comment: This should probably be migrated somewhere else, as it isn't an issue with already written code yet is not a bad question. Maybe to CS?

Comment: For 2d but relevant: http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/march12014/index.html

Comment: @Tharwen I added new approach into my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. **find two closest points in each polygons**

   this will be used as start point
2. **reorder vertexes from this two start points**

   with the same **winding rule** for example **CW** like on image
3. **find 'center' points for each polygon**

   for example average of all vertexes or mid point of bounding box or whatever. It does not need to be precise but on complex concave shapes wrongly selected  center position will cause errors in output mesh.
4. **add angular info for each vertex**

   angle is easy just use

   ```
   a=atan2(vertex-center)
   ```

After all this it should looks like this:

[image: polygons]

for angle angle [deg]

```
index: 0   1   2   3   4
green: 355 085 135 170 230 
 blue: 020 135 255
```

Now you just match 2 closest vertexes from one polygon to the other

do not forget that angle difference is max `+/-180 deg` and also if you use radians then convert constants `180,360` to `PI,2.0*PI`

```
da=ang1-ang0;
while (da<-180.0) da+=360.0;
while (da>+180.0) da-=360.0;
if (da<0.0) da=-da;
```

for next text `line(i,j)` will mean `i-th` vertex from green and `j-th` vertex from blue polygon

Now the joining:

1. **join closest vertexes**

   just process all green vertexes and join them to closest blue vertex (black lines on image)

   ```
   line(0,0)
   line(1,1)
   line(2,1)
   line(3,1)
   line(4,2)
   ```
2. **fill the holes**

   mesh triangulation need at least 2 joints per vertex so process points that have less connections:

   ```
               index: 0 1 2 3 4
   green connections: 1 1 1 1 1
    blue connections: 1 3 1
   ```

   so now process less then 2 times used blue vertexes `(0,2)` and join them to closest green vertex (yellow lines on image) ignoring already used connection (chose next one in that case)

   ```
   line(1,0)
   line(3,2)
   ```

   so:

   ```
               index: 0 1 2 3 4
   green connections: 1 2 1 2 1
    blue connections: 2 3 2
   ```

   now process the rest of green less then 2 times used vertexes joined to less then 3 times used blue vertex. Chose just the next point to already used connection if it has less then 3 connections and if there are more then 1 option use the closest one (red lines on  image).

`line(0,2)` green 0 is connected to blue 0 so choose from blue 1,2 (1 is too used so 2)

`line(2,-)` green 2 is connected to blue 1 which is 3 times used so ignore this vertex

`line(4,-)` green 4 is connected to blue 2 which is 3 times used so ignore this vertex

```
                index: 0 1 2 3 4
    green connections: 2 2 1 2 1
     blue connections: 2 3 3
```

and that is it all. Now you should have the tesselation done like this:

[image: mesh]

**[notes]**

- you can also use perimeter position / perimeter length instead of angle (sometimes it have better results)
- concave polygons can mess this up a lot so there should be added some triangle intersection checks to avoid problems.
- also the number of vertexes should not differ too much between polygons in that case you can still divide some lines to add missing points otherwise that 3 times usage conditions will be wrong (if the vertex count differs 2 or more times)
- if you want to be safe you should cut polygons to convex parts and tesselate them separately and only after that join the meshes back together

**[Edit1] new approach less susceptible to concavity and points density**

Its slower but looks its working for more complex shapes. As example I took the modified star and plus sign from the comments.

1. **find two closest points in each polygons**

   this will be used as start point
2. **reorder vertexes from this two start points**

   with the same winding rule for example CW like on image
3. **prepare edge lists**

   we will need a structure holding all the connections between polygons. I decided to something like this:

   ```cpp
   List< List<int> > edg0,edg1;
   ```

   where `edg0[point0][i]` is holding `i-th` `point1` connected to point0. Beware in the code array index is the point index and the actual value n the array is point index in a global point table `pnt` where I can transform between the two like this:

   ```
   point0 = (pnt_index - ix0)/3 
   point1 = (pnt_index - ix1)/3 
   pnt_index = ix0 + 3*point0
   pnt_index = ix1 + 3*point1
   ```

   where `ix0,ix1` are start indexes in `pnt` for each polygon.
4. **join close points**

   Instead of joining to the closest points I added thresholding so the point distance must be smaller than threshold `minll`. This threshold is a multiply of the distance of the 2 start points (min distance). In code:

   ```
   minll=2.5*l0;
   ```

   but beware I am comparing `distance^2` for speed so if you got distance it would be

   ```
   minl=sqrt(2.5)*l0;
   ```

   The multiply coefficient can be tweaked ...

   [image: join close points]

   as you can see the distant point on star is not connected due thresholding.
5. **fill unused holes in points0**

   simply find sequence of unused points0 and then interpolate the join from start to end with first neighbors that are connected. so if points0 `i0 .. i1`  are unconnected and their closest neighbors are connected take their closest connected points1 `j0 .. j1` and simply linearly connect point `i` with `j` where:

   ```
   i = i0 + t*(i1-i0)
   j = j0 + t*(j1-j0)
   ```

   where `t` is parameter `t=<0.0,1.0>` going through all "integer" point indexes. (use DDA).

   [image: holes0]
6. **fill unused holes in points1**

   its the same as **#5** but look for the unconnected points1 in the other polygon.

   [image: holes1]
7. **find&connect singular connection lines**

   both endpoints are used just once. So simply find such edge and connect it to neighboring points.

   [image: singular lines]
8. **find singular `poinst0` that form QUAD hole and triangulate it**

   so find `point0` that is connected just once and then test its neighbors if the are connected back to the `point1` the first one was connected to. If no you found QUAD hole so triangulate it.

   [image: Quad holes]
9. **now just extract triangles and lines from the `edg0,edg1`**

   line are simple as they are already encoded directly, for triangles simply search neighboring `point0` for connection to the same `point1`. If found form a triangle. the triangles should be formed also in the other edge list so search neighboring `point1` that are connected to the same `point0` too.

**Here GL/C++ example**

```cpp
List<double> pnt;
List<int> lin,tri;
int iy0=0,iy1=0,iy2=0,iy3=0;// pol0<iy0,iy1),pol1<iy1,iy2),merge<iy2,iy3)
int ix0=0,ix1=0,ix2=0;      // points1<ix0,ix1), points2<ix1,ix2)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void obj_init()
    {
    // input data
    const double d=0.5;             // distance between polygons
    const double pol0[]={0.0,2.0, 1.0,2.0, 1.0,3.0, 2.00,3.0, 2.0,2.0, 3.00,2.0, 3.0,1.0, 2.0,1.0, 2.0,0.0, 1.0,0.0, 1.0,1.0, 0.0,1.0, 0.0,2.0};
//  const double pol1[]={0.0,0.0, 1.0,1.0, 0.0,2.0, 1.25,1.5, 1.5,2.5, 1.75,1.5, 3.0,2.0, 2.0,1.0, 3.0,0.0, 1.5,0.7};
    const double pol1[]={0.0,0.0, 1.0,1.0, 0.0,2.0, 1.25,1.5, 1.5,5.0, 1.75,1.5, 3.0,2.0, 2.0,1.0, 3.0,0.0, 1.5,0.7};
//                                                                ***
    // variables
    List<double> tmp;
    List< List<int> > edg0,edg1;    // edge table

    double minll;                   // max distance to points that will join automatically
    double p[3],l0,l;
    int i,i0,i1,ii,ii0,ii1,di;
    int j,j0,j1,jj,jj0,jj1,dj;
    int k,n0,n1,e,de;
    pnt.num=0;
    lin.num=0;

    // copy pol0 to point list pnt[]
    ix0=pnt.num;
    n0=sizeof(pol0)/sizeof(pol0[0]);
    for (j=pnt.num,i=0;i<n0;)
        {
        pnt.add(pol0[i]); i++;
        pnt.add(pol0[i]); i++;
        pnt.add(-d);
        } ix1=pnt.num; n0/=2;

    // copy pol1 to point list pnt[]
    n1=sizeof(pol1)/sizeof(pol1[0]);
    for (j=pnt.num,i=0;i<n1;)
        {
        pnt.add(pol1[i]); i++;
        pnt.add(pol1[i]); i++;
        pnt.add(+d);
        } ix2=pnt.num; n1/=2;

    // add polygon edges
    iy0=lin.num;
    for (j=ix1-3,i=ix0;i<ix1;j=i,i+=3){ lin.add(j); lin.add(i); } iy1=lin.num;
    for (j=ix2-3,i=ix1;i<ix2;j=i,i+=3){ lin.add(j); lin.add(i); } iy2=lin.num;

    // find closest points -> start points i0,j0
    i0=-1; j0=-1; l0=0.0; minll=0.0;
    for (i=ix0;i<ix1;i+=3)
     for (j=ix1;j<ix2;j+=3)
        {
        vector_sub(p,pnt.dat+i,pnt.dat+j);
        l=vector_len2(p);
        if ((i0<0)||(l<l0)){ l0=l; i0=i; j0=j; }
        } minll=2.5*l0;
    // reorder points so closest ones are first
    if (i0!=ix0)
        {
        tmp.num=0;  for (i=ix0;i<ix1;i++) tmp.add(pnt.dat[i]);                          // copy to temp
        for (j=i0,i=ix0;i<ix1;i++,j++,(j>=ix1)?j=ix0:j=j) pnt.dat[i]=tmp.dat[j-ix0];    // reorder
        }
    if (j0!=ix1)
        {
        tmp.num=0;  for (i=ix1;i<ix2;i++) tmp.add(pnt.dat[i]);                          // copy to temp
        for (j=j0,i=ix1;i<ix2;i++,j++,(j>=ix2)?j=ix1:j=j) pnt.dat[i]=tmp.dat[j-ix1];    // reorder
        }

    // init edge lists
    edg0.allocate(n0); edg0.num=n0; for (i=0;i<n0;i++) edg0[i].num=0;
    edg1.allocate(n1); edg1.num=n1; for (i=0;i<n1;i++) edg1[i].num=0;

    // join close points
    for (ii=0,i=ix0;i<ix1;i+=3,ii++)
        {
        j0=-1; jj0=-1; l0=0.0;
        for (jj=0,j=ix1;j<ix2;j+=3,jj++)
            {
            vector_sub(p,pnt.dat+i,pnt.dat+j);
            l=vector_len2(p);
            if ((j0<0)||(l<l0)){ l0=l; j0=j; jj0=jj; }
            }
        if ((j0>=0)&&(l0<minll))
            {
            edg0.dat[ii ].add(j0);
            edg1.dat[jj0].add(i);
            }
        }

    // fill unused holes in points0
    for (e=1,i=0;e;)
        {
        e=0;
        // find last used point0 -> i0
        i0=-1; i1=-1;
        for (j=0;j<n0;j++,i++,(i==n0)?i=0:i=i) if (edg0.dat[i].num) i0=i; else if (i0>=0) break;
        // find next used point0 -> i1
        if (i0>=0) if (edg0.dat[i].num==0)
         for (j=0;j<n0;j++,i++,(i==n0)?i=0:i=i) if (edg0.dat[i].num){ i1=i; break; }
        if (i1>=0)
            {
            // find last used point1 joined to i0 -> j0
            j0=-1; jj0=-1; l0=0.0;
            i=i0+1; if (i>=n0) i=0; ii=ix0+i+i+i;
            for (j=0;j<edg0.dat[i0].num;j++)
                {
                jj=edg0.dat[i0].dat[j];
                vector_sub(p,pnt.dat+ii,pnt.dat+jj);
                l=vector_len2(p);
                if ((j0<0)||(l<l0)){ l0=l; j0=(jj-ix1)/3; jj0=jj; }
                } i0=i;
            // find next used point1 joined to i1 -> j1
            j1=-1; jj1=-1; l0=0.0;
            i=i1-1; if (i<0) i=n0-1; ii=ix0+i+i+i;
            for (j=0;j<edg0.dat[i1].num;j++)
                {
                jj=edg0.dat[i1].dat[j];
                vector_sub(p,pnt.dat+ii,pnt.dat+jj);
                l=vector_len2(p);
                if ((j1<0)||(l<l0)){ l0=l; j1=(jj-ix1)/3; jj1=jj; }
                } i1=i;
            // join i0..i1 <-> j0..j1
            di=i1-i0; if (di<0) di+=n0; // point0 to join
            dj=j1-j0; if (dj<0) dj+=n1; // point1 to join
            de=di; if (de<dj) de=dj;    // max(points0,point1)
            for (e=0;e<=de;e++)
                {
                i=i0+((e*di)/de); if (i>=n0) i-=n0; ii=ix0+i+i+i;
                j=j0+((e*di)/de); if (j>=n1) j-=n1; jj=ix1+j+j+j;
                for (k=0;k<edg0.dat[i].num;k++) // avoid duplicate edges
                 if (edg0.dat[i].dat[k]==jj)
                  { k=-1; break; }
                if (k>=0)
                    {
                    edg0.dat[i].add(jj);
                    edg1.dat[j].add(ii);
                    }
                }
            e=1;
            }
        }

    // fill unused holes in points1
    for (e=1,i=0;e;)
        {
        e=0;
        // find last used point1 -> i0
        i0=-1; i1=-1;
        for (j=0;j<n1;j++,i++,(i==n1)?i=0:i=i) if (edg1.dat[i].num) i0=i; else if (i0>=0) break;
        // find next used point1 -> i1
        if (i0>=0) if (edg1.dat[i].num==0)
         for (j=0;j<n1;j++,i++,(i==n1)?i=0:i=i) if (edg1.dat[i].num){ i1=i; break; }
        if (i1>=0)
            {
            // find last used point0 joined to i0 -> j0
            j0=-1; jj0=-1; l0=0.0;
            i=i0+1; if (i>=n1) i=0; ii=ix1+i+i+i;
            for (j=0;j<edg1.dat[i0].num;j++)
                {
                jj=edg1.dat[i0].dat[j];
                vector_sub(p,pnt.dat+ii,pnt.dat+jj);
                l=vector_len2(p);
                if ((j0<0)||(l<l0)){ l0=l; j0=(jj-ix0)/3; jj0=jj; }
                } i0=i;
            // find next used point0 joined to i1 -> j1
            j1=-1; jj1=-1; l0=0.0;
            i=i1-1; if (i<0) i=n1-1; ii=ix1+i+i+i;
            for (j=0;j<edg1.dat[i1].num;j++)
                {
                jj=edg1.dat[i1].dat[j];
                vector_sub(p,pnt.dat+ii,pnt.dat+jj);
                l=vector_len2(p);
                if ((j1<0)||(l<l0)){ l0=l; j1=(jj-ix0)/3; jj1=jj; }
                } i1=i;
            // join i0..i1 <-> j0..j1
            di=i1-i0; if (di<0) di+=n1; // point1 to join
            dj=j1-j0; if (dj<0) dj+=n0; // point0 to join
            de=di; if (de<dj) de=dj;    // max(points0,point1)
            for (e=0;e<=de;e++)
                {
                i=i0+((e*di)/de); if (i>=n1) i-=n1; ii=ix1+i+i+i;
                j=j0+((e*di)/de); if (j>=n0) j-=n0; jj=ix0+j+j+j;
                for (k=0;k<edg1.dat[i].num;k++) // avoid duplicate edges
                 if (edg1.dat[i].dat[k]==jj)
                  { k=-1; break; }
                if (k>=0)
                    {
                    edg1.dat[i].add(jj);
                    edg0.dat[j].add(ii);
                    }
                }
            e=1;
            }
        }

    // find&connect singular connection lines (both endpoints are used just once)
    for (i=0;i<n0;i++)
     if (edg0.dat[i].num==1)    // point0 used once
        {
        jj=edg0.dat[i].dat[0];  // connected to
        j=(jj-ix1)/3;
        if (edg1.dat[j].num==1) // point1 used once
            {
            i0=i-1; if (i<  0) i+=n0;   // point0 neighbors
            i1=i+1; if (i>=n0) i-=n0;
            ii =ix0+i +i +i;
            ii0=ix0+i0+i0+i0;
            ii1=ix0+i1+i1+i1;
            if (edg1.dat[j].dat[0]!=ii0)    // avoid duplicate edges
                {
                edg1.dat[j].add(ii0);
                edg0.dat[i0].add(jj);
                }
            if (edg1.dat[j].dat[0]!=ii1)    // avoid duplicate edges
                {
                edg1.dat[j].add(ii1);
                edg0.dat[i1].add(jj);
                }
            }
        }

    // find singular poinst0 that form QUAD hole and triangulate it
    for (i=0;i<n0;i++)
     if (edg0.dat[i].num==1)    // point0 used once
        {
        jj=edg0.dat[i].dat[0];  // connected to
        j=(jj-ix1)/3;
        i0=i-1; if (i<  0) i+=n0;   // point0 neighbors
        i1=i+1; if (i>=n0) i-=n0;
        j0=j-1; if (j<  0) j+=n1;   // point1 neighbors
        j1=j+1; if (j>=n1) j-=n1;
        ii =ix0+i +i +i;
        ii0=ix0+i0+i0+i0;
        ii1=ix0+i1+i1+i1;
        jj0=ix1+j0+j0+j0;
        jj1=ix1+j1+j1+j1;
        for (k=0;k<edg1.dat[j].num;k++) // avoid duplicate edges
            {
            if (edg1.dat[j].dat[k]==ii0) i0=-1;
            if (edg1.dat[j].dat[k]==ii1) i1=-1;
            }
        if (i0>=0)
            {
            edg1.dat[j ].add(ii0);
            edg0.dat[i0].add(jj );
            }
        if (i1>=0)
            {
            edg1.dat[j ].add(ii1);
            edg0.dat[i1].add(jj );
            }
        }

    // extract merge triangles from edge0
    for (i0=0,i1=1;i0<n0;i0++,i1++,(i1>=n0)?i1=0:i1=i1)
        {
        ii0=ix0+i0+i0+i0;
        ii1=ix0+i1+i1+i1;
        // find point1 joined to both points0 i0,i1
        for (i=0;i<edg0.dat[i0].num;i++)
         for (j=0;j<edg0.dat[i1].num;j++)
          if (edg0.dat[i0].dat[i]==edg0.dat[i1].dat[j])
            {
            jj=edg0.dat[i0].dat[i];
            tri.add(ii0);
            tri.add(ii1);
            tri.add(jj);
            }
        }
    // extract merge triangles from edge1
    for (i0=0,i1=1;i0<n1;i0++,i1++,(i1>=n1)?i1=0:i1=i1)
        {
        ii0=ix1+i0+i0+i0;
        ii1=ix1+i1+i1+i1;
        // find point1 joined to both points0 i0,i1
        for (i=0;i<edg1.dat[i0].num;i++)
         for (j=0;j<edg1.dat[i1].num;j++)
          if (edg1.dat[i0].dat[i]==edg1.dat[i1].dat[j])
            {
            jj=edg1.dat[i0].dat[i];
            tri.add(ii0);
            tri.add(ii1);
            tri.add(jj);
            }
        }

    // extract merge edges
    for (i=ix0,ii=0;ii<n0;ii++,i+=3)
     for (j=0;j<edg0.dat[ii].num;j++)
        {
        lin.add(i);
        lin.add(edg0.dat[ii].dat[j]);
        }
    iy3=lin.num;

/*
    // [debug]
    AnsiString txt="";
    for (txt+="[edg0]\r\n",i=0;i<n0;i++,txt+="\r\n")
     for (txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("%2i:",i),j=0;j<edg0.dat[i].num;j++)
      txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("%2i ",(edg0.dat[i].dat[j]-ix1)/3);
    for (txt+="\r\n[edg1]\r\n",i=0;i<n1;i++,txt+="\r\n")
     for (txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("%2i:",i),j=0;j<edg1.dat[i].num;j++)
      txt+=AnsiString().sprintf("%2i ",(edg1.dat[i].dat[j]-ix0)/3);
    e=FileCreate("debug.txt");
    FileWrite(e,txt.c_str(),txt.Length());
    FileClose(e);
*/
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void obj_draw()
    {
    int i,j;
    glLineWidth(2.0);
    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1); glBegin(GL_LINES); for (i=0;(i<iy0)&&(i<lin.num);i++) glVertex3dv(pnt.dat+lin.dat[i]); glEnd(); // aux
    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.9); glBegin(GL_LINES); for (   ;(i<iy1)&&(i<lin.num);i++) glVertex3dv(pnt.dat+lin.dat[i]); glEnd(); // polygon 0
    glColor3f(0.9,0.1,0.1); glBegin(GL_LINES); for (   ;(i<iy2)&&(i<lin.num);i++) glVertex3dv(pnt.dat+lin.dat[i]); glEnd(); // polygon 1
    glColor3f(0.1,0.9,0.1); glBegin(GL_LINES); for (   ;(i<iy3)&&(i<lin.num);i++) glVertex3dv(pnt.dat+lin.dat[i]); glEnd(); // merge
    glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.1); glBegin(GL_LINES); for (   ;         (i<lin.num);i++) glVertex3dv(pnt.dat+lin.dat[i]); glEnd(); // aux
    glLineWidth(1.0);

    glPointSize(5.0);
    glColor3f(0.9,0.9,0.1); glBegin(GL_POINTS); glVertex3dv(pnt.dat+ix0+0); glVertex3dv(pnt.dat+ix1+0); glEnd();    // 1st points
    glColor3f(0.1,0.9,0.9); glBegin(GL_POINTS); glVertex3dv(pnt.dat+ix0+3); glVertex3dv(pnt.dat+ix1+3); glEnd();    // 2nd points
    glColor3f(0.3,0.3,0.3); glBegin(GL_POINTS); for (i=0;i<pnt.num;i+=3) glVertex3dv(pnt.dat+i); glEnd();           // points
    glPointSize(1.0);

    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glColor3f(0.2,0.2,0.2); glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); for (i=0;i<tri.num;i++) glVertex3dv(pnt.dat+tri.dat[i]); glEnd();    // faces
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also use mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

Comment: This was really helpful. I implemented this but am having one difficulty. Finding the "center point" isn't do simple. I think because the algorithm doesn't really want to use a true center point, but instead a good point to perform a CW or CCW sweep. I tried using a 5 point "star" shaped concave polygon. The algorithm fails to match verticies properly if you modify the star slightly (by pulling one of the start point vertexes up), since now the center point moves and is above most points in the poly. Average and bounding box "centers" both have this issue. Another heuristic maybe... hmm...

Comment: Thanks again for looking into this. Here is a link with the 2D polygon points and some screenshots. https://pastebin.com/EDznU8Fq  Screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/oPKuPxz

Comment: @AlexAmato the modification makes the vertex too far from center (too big edges in comparison to average size) which with the concavity makes the problem... The easiest solution is to re-sample such edges (add some point to shrink the size of edges) as suggested in the answer.  When I will have the time will implement this (**C++**) and post here ... The resampling is the only thing left the rest is done already.

Comment: Okay thank you, that would be very helpful. I am not sure exactly how to do the re-sampling step. I appreciate it :).

Comment: @AlexAmato that is easy compute average edge size and then all edges bigger than some multiple of it (like `1.25*avg_size`) divide into smaller lines simply by adding some points by linear interpolation if edge is `p0,p1` then `p(t) = p0 + t*(p1-p0)` where `t=<0.0,1.0>` so if edge is twice as big as avg size add one point (t=0.5) ... if triple add 2 points (`t=0.333, t=0.666`) etc ... How ever I am thinking of a new approach that would not be sensitive to such things but will not have time for it at least till tomorrow

Comment: @AlexAmato The new approach I am thinking of is using topology of both polygons so the edges will not cross neighbors. That should improve handling concave polygons but need testing and elaborating... Current approach can be remedied too but there is a risc of internal face creation that screws its neighbors without dividing into convex polygons and testing if face is inside still non existing shape is hard ...

Comment: I was thinking about an approach like that as well. I was wondering if you could Do a first pass and assign a matching vert for every vert in the polygon A. Then assign any verts that were not yet assigned in polygon B to verts in polygon A, but being careful not to introduce any crossings. So you could look at nearby verts which were assigned and fill in the holes without crossing.

Though I think you have a point, that even the first pass could possibly produce crossings.

Comment: @AlexAmato You're right after some trials yesterday the first pass is creating crossings already (even after resampling) ... I returned back to the original algo .. I want to try the "arc" length as parameter instead of angle if it makes any difference. If even that will not work then only checking inside mesh or dividing to convex shape is the only way I can see ...

Comment: Take your time. Thank you so much for your help with this problem. It really turnes out to be a tricky one :). I am excited to see how you solved it.

Comment: @AlexAmato I added promised stuff as an [edit1]. Was afraid I hit the 30K limit again but luckily all stuff together fitted without error :)

Comment: Oh, I like the screenshots. Looks like a very good result! I was thinking of a very similar approach, but I did not think about the minimum distance requirement. I think this helps with the result a lot. Thanks so much @Spektre. I'm going to give this a try in my implementation as well.

Comment: @AlexAmato me neither at first but after some trial&error and tweaking I drop the angled and arclength metrics return to slow euklid and add thresholding removing wrong edges (along with many good ones) and using topology (order of points) to fill in the gaps instead Now I a returned to another older geometry project of mine: [4D rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44970550/2521214) creating UI for config, new meshes and stuff