# Helix Toolkit: How to connect X,Y,Z points

Tags: c#, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I have a file that contains points from a real object profiles. The data are X,Y,Z coordinates and I want to connect each point of the profile and then display the next profile behind the previous profile. This way a series of profiles will be created, like a 3D object (but not an object).

But using Helix Toolkit I didn't find a way to connect points together with a Line or PolyLine. The only way to connect them, was with Tubes etc. which was not good.
Right now, I am using a Rectangular Mesh to connect my profile points, which if I zoom in I kinda looks like a line but it is not.

In this image I demonstrate a series of mesh profiles. On the bottom I have the first mesh from the data files that contains the points, exactly over the first profile is the second profile which have different X,Y,Z coordinates and this carries on for all the profiles.
[image: My example Mesh]

The reason I don't want this implementation is because I need to give color to different areas of the mesh according to X,Y coordinates. If I has low X for example I want to give a red color.
But in Helix Toolkit I didn't find a way to dynamically color the mesh.

Another solution that I tried, was to draw each data point as a sphere using the Point3D object, but because of the amount of spheres that were created the program was laggy (each profile has at least 700 points and I want to draw at least 400 profiles on series)

I am open to suggestion, even if they require different toolkits etc.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The image looks weird, like a wire-frame. I would generate a solid mesh and use a generated texture together with uv coordinates for coloring each vertex.

Comment: What I do in the picture is the following:
Firstly I read all the data for one profile, and I generate a Point3D and add it to a List<Point3D>, when I finish the points, I use AddRectangular mesh to create the 1 profile mesh.
I do this for each profile that I have in my data file and this is the result.

Comment: How can I generate a solid mesh using only the points? Can be done through Helix? or should I use another approach?

Comment: I usually just generate a vertex and index list by hand, it should be fairly straightforward for a simple shape like this.

Comment: What I want to do with the different colors on each 3D point is to visual see if there is any damage on the real object, if some points have low X,Y values I should color them Red to indicate the damage. 
Vertices are included in Helix? what will change using vertices instead of point3d objects?

Comment: wpf 3d, including Helix, uses [MeshGeometry3D] for most objects. As you can see in the example this has positions (aka vertices), TriangleIndices and TextureCoordinates (aka uv-coordinates). These can be created directly, you do not have to use the built in shapes like point and cylinders.

Comment: I think I understood what you want to say, instead of creating a new object every time, just add to the MeshGeometry3D mesh object the Position of the new point and the Index of the Triangle. 
Every time I read a new point I do the following:
mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(temp_point.dX, temp_point.dY, zeta));
mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(i);
This creates a similar shape as the photo of the post but I don't use any Shape of Helix.
Do you know how I can create or use a texture coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

- If your point structure is "organized", meaning row by row you could have a look at my answer here : [Going from a point cloud to a solid mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966648/going-from-a-point-cloud-to-a-solid-mesh/52026122#52026122)
- if (as in your picture) your points lie on a quasi plane, you could project them into 2D space and use Delaunay Triangulation (pretty fast) then project back into 3D.
- else, (for general point clouds) there are many algorithms... each with advantages and drawbacks.

  - Crust
  - Poisson reconstruction
  - Super Cocone